# How do I export an OBJ to an .X file

Tags: export

I just downloaded blender 2.70 windows 64. I want to convert .obj files to .X files to use then in the pmd editor and MMD. I cant find an export to .x file. the tutorial that I am looking at is for an older version of Blender.

Comment: AFIK not all import/export scripts have been ported to the new Python API. But if you know on which Blender version it worked you can download the old release [here](http://download.blender.org/release/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the export option for `.x` is there. Look again. If not you must have disabled it.

Answer (score 4):

### Enabling Import & Export of DirectX 3D Model file format .X

Blender 2.70 comes with the "DirectX X Format" Export addon built-in.

However, the "DirectX Importer" Import addon is ***not*** built-in. If you'd like to have the ability to import .X files, you can download it in [this addon bundle](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?330884-Blender-2-70-released-!&p=2602818&viewfull=1#post2602818).   (**Note:** that post describes how to add the addon to Blender's scripts folder.)

To enable these:

1. Info header -> File -> User Preferences

   [image]
2. Then, in the search box, type Direct. Two DirectX addons will appear:

   - The one named "DirectX Importer" provides the ability to **Import** .X files
     The one named "DirectX X Format" provides the ability to **Export** .X files
   - Check the checkbox at the right hand side of the addon to enable it
   - If you want to always have these import/export options in your File menu, then click on the Save User Settings button at the bottom of the screen:

   [image]
3. You will then have the .X file format as import & export options:

   [image]