# How to export OBJ files in .X files (direct X) from Blender 2.91.2?

Tags: export

How do I export OBJ files in .X files (direct X) format from Blender ver.2.91.2?  The game object editor that I'm working with only imports files in the .X (directx format).  There appears to be no add on available to activate under the edit/preferences/import-export tab.

The 2 answers I found by searching are from 2013 and 2014 and don't cover the latest version of Blender. The tabs and UI have changed between the two versions. [link to answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8740/how-do-i-export-an-obj-to-an-x-file)  It appears that it was possible with an older version (2.7X) of Blender, but not the current one.